# Problem with state changing in Firestore with switch and flutter true and false

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a switch which should change state of the user between isOnline or not.
this is a bool between true and false.
I created a method with cupertino switch:

```
bool isOnline = true;
```

the original state is true so the user see they are available online

in the cupertino switch I create a function:

```
CupertinoSwitch(
                      value: isOnline,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        setState(() {
                          changeState();
                          isOnline = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
```

and I need to update firestore collection:

```
 CollectionReference changestate = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Consultant');
  Future<void> changeState() {
    var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return changestate
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .update({
      'isOnline': isOnline,
    },)
```

all works but inside out... when I turn the switch to green it return on the database `false` and if I turn off it return `true`
any suggestion please?

Comment: There's many things that aren't being done right here. If you're only going to update a single value, why not try firebase realtime database? Firestore has a different use case and it is not for simple boolean changes. You will get charged a lot. Also, if you wanna get better at Flutter, you have to learn state management. SetState() rebuilds the entire screen and is costly. I suggest learning Provider first then Bloc: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue in your on state code call

```
isOnline = value;
```

After

```
changeState();
```

method.

Like this,

```
CupertinoSwitch(
    value: isOnline,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
         setState(() { 
           isOnline = value; 
           changeState();      
          }); 
        }, 
      ),
```